# SQL for xml auto elements wrap node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, for-xml

I have the following code:

```
SELECT distinct 
msi.SupplierNumber
    ,Province.[Name] [ProvinceName]
    ,District.[Code] [DistrictCode]
    ,District.[Name] [DistrictName]
    ,Municipality.[Code] [MunicipalityCode]
    ,Municipality.[Name] [MunicipalityName]
    ,City.[Code] [CityCode]
    ,City.[Name] [CityName]
    ,Suburb.[Code] [SuburbCode]
    ,Suburb.[Name] [SuburbName]
    ,Ward.[Code] [WardCode]
FROM
    dbo.MasterSupplierIdentification msi WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN dbo.[LinkMasterSupplierCommodity] lmsc WITH (NOLOCK) ON lmsc.MasterSupplierIdentificationID = msi.MasterSupplierIdentificationID
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MasterCommodityGroup] mcg WITH (NOLOCK) ON mcg.[MasterCommodityGroupID] = lmsc.MasterCommodityID
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MasterCommodityLocation] mcl WITH (NOLOCK) ON mcl.[MasterCommodityID] = mcg.[MasterCommodityID]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MDWard] Ward WITH (NOLOCK) ON Ward.[WardID] = mcl.[WardID]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MDSuburb] Suburb WITH (NOLOCK) ON Suburb.[SuburbID] = Ward.[SuburbID]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MDCity] City WITH (NOLOCK) ON City.[CityID] = Suburb.[CityID]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MDMunicipality] Municipality WITH (NOLOCK) ON Municipality.[MunicipalityID] = City.[MunicipalityID]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MDDistrict] District WITH (NOLOCK) ON District.[DistrictID] = Municipality.[DistrictID]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MDProvince] Province WITH (NOLOCK) ON Province.[ProvinceID] = District.[ProvinceID]
WHERE 
    msi.SupplierNumber = 'MAAA0000002'
    and Suburb.Code = '181001001'
for xml auto, Root('Suppliers'), elements xsinil
```

Which returns:

```
<Suppliers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <msi>
        <SupplierNumber>MAAA0000002</SupplierNumber>
        <Province>
        <ProvinceName>Western Cape</ProvinceName>
            <District>
            <DistrictCode>105</DistrictCode>
            <DistrictName>Central Karoo</DistrictName>
                <Municipality>
                <MunicipalityCode>181</MunicipalityCode>
                <MunicipalityName>Laingsburg</MunicipalityName>
                    <City>
                    <CityCode>181001</CityCode>
                    <CityName>Laingsburg NU</CityName>
                        <Suburb>
                        <SuburbCode>181001001</SuburbCode>
                        <SuburbName>Laingsburg NU</SuburbName>
                            <Ward>
                                <WardCode>1</WardCode>
                            </Ward>
                            <Ward>
                                <WardCode>12</WardCode>
                            </Ward>
                            <Ward>
                                <WardCode>2</WardCode>
                            </Ward>
                       </Suburb>
                   </City>
               </Municipality>
           </District>
       </Province>
  </msi>
```

In this specific example, the Wards repeat. I would like to have it wrapped in a parent node . Seems the only way to do this is to use sub query where I specify not AUTO but PATH and ROOT in the sub query and return it as TYPE.

Answer (score 0):

Your final sentence is correct. If you want to see nested data (1:many relations) wrapped in a parent node, you must include them as one block.

One hint: You use `WITH (NOLOCK)` everywhere. Unless you really know what you are doing an unless you have a quite good reason for this, this is a dangerous thing. Very common, but not good practice...

Try it like this (untested):

```
SELECT distinct 
msi.SupplierNumber
    ,Province.[Name] [ProvinceName]
    ,District.[Code] [DistrictCode]
    ,District.[Name] [DistrictName]
    ,Municipality.[Code] [MunicipalityCode]
    ,Municipality.[Name] [MunicipalityName]
    ,City.[Code] [CityCode]
    ,City.[Name] [CityName]
    ,Suburb.[Code] [SuburbCode]
    ,Suburb.[Name] [SuburbName]

    ,WardXml.XmlAsBlock
FROM
    dbo.MasterSupplierIdentification msi WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN dbo.[LinkMasterSupplierCommodity] lmsc WITH (NOLOCK) ON lmsc.MasterSupplierIdentificationID = msi.MasterSupplierIdentificationID
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MasterCommodityGroup] mcg WITH (NOLOCK) ON mcg.[MasterCommodityGroupID] = lmsc.MasterCommodityID
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MasterCommodityLocation] mcl WITH (NOLOCK) ON mcl.[MasterCommodityID] = mcg.[MasterCommodityID]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MDWard] Ward WITH (NOLOCK) ON Ward.[WardID] = mcl.[WardID]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MDSuburb] Suburb WITH (NOLOCK) ON Suburb.[SuburbID] = Ward.[SuburbID]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MDCity] City WITH (NOLOCK) ON City.[CityID] = Suburb.[CityID]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MDMunicipality] Municipality WITH (NOLOCK) ON Municipality.[MunicipalityID] = City.[MunicipalityID]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MDDistrict] District WITH (NOLOCK) ON District.[DistrictID] = Municipality.[DistrictID]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[MDProvince] Province WITH (NOLOCK) ON Province.[ProvinceID] = District.[ProvinceID]

    CROSS APPLY
    (
      SELECT WardCode FROM dbo.[MDWard] Ward WITH (NOLOCK) 
      WHERE Ward.[WardID] = mcl.[WardID]
      FOR XML PATH('Ward'),TYPE
    ) AS WardXml(XmlAsBlock)
WHERE 
    msi.SupplierNumber = 'MAAA0000002'
    and Suburb.Code = '181001001'
for xml auto, Root('Suppliers'), elements xsinil
```

Comment: Thank you. NOLOCK is explicit decision and I am aware of the consequences. The query fails and I'm not a SQL master so even though I understand the principle I can't get the query to work. I'm getting: ".Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 19 The multi-part identifier "Ward.SuburbID" could not be bound. .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable."----The type results in the DISTINCT issue which I understand, but the block, the notation and suburbid I don't.

Comment: @japieson, Yes, I did not see the `Ward-SuburbID`. Try my edited version. One possible problem could be, that the joins below your Ward-join might deliver more than one row. In this case, all data should be nested... That's up to you. Try without the DISTINCT and come back if you cannot resolve this. I hope this  solves your issue and you'll vote this up and accept it with the check below the vote counter, Thx

Comment: Distinct throws exception due to the xml being returned as a type. If I remove the distinct, or the type to get rid of that problem, the wards still isn't wrapped. The WardXml node repeats for every ward, so I still don't have a parent wrapping wards. I'm showing partial result: <SuburbName>Laingsburg NU</SuburbName>
              <WardXml>
                <XmlAsBlock>
                  <Ward>
                    <WardCode>10206012001815</WardCode>
                  </Ward>
                </XmlAsBlock>
              </WardXml>